# Compiler error attempting to access substring when traversing a string

Tags: c++, string, stl, iterator

I am trying in vain to find a way to parse a text file stored in a `string` object. The format of the string is as follows:

```
...
1  45
1  46
1  47
2  43
2  44
2  45
...
```

I am trying to iterate over the whole string, grab each line, and then split the string by the first integer and the second integer for further processing. However, doing something like this doesn't work:

```
string  fileContents;

string::iterator index;

for(index = fileContents.begin(); index != fileContents.end(); ++index)
{
   cout << (*index);       // this works as expected

   // grab a substring representing one line of the file
   string temp = (*index); // error: trying to assign const char to const char*
}
```

I am trying to find a way to do this, but so far I haven't had any luck.

Comment: You are assigning a char to a string which is not allowed. What do you want?

Comment: Yes, I know. From the above: "I am trying to iterate over a the whole string, grab each line, and then split the string by the first integer and the second integer for further processing.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to ask if there is a way to iterate over the string and assign the index of each iteration to a new string?

Comment: I see the problem here - I was thinking that the index was pointing at one *line* of characters - which would indeed be an array of chars, but the index is just pointing at a single character. Yet another face-palm moment for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)s and [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to obtain the integers from each line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream in("1 45\n1 47\n");
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        std::istringstream nums(line);
        int i1, i2;
        if (nums >> i1 && nums >> i2)
        {
            std::cout << i1 << ", " << i2 << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/mFmynj .

Comment: One question though: how did the stream extraction operator know where to get the appropriate substring? I.e., did it treat the `space` as a delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

A `std::string::iterator` identifies a `char`. A `char` can possibly be used to form a one element `std::string` but this probably not what you want. Instead, you can use two iterators to create a `std::string`, e.g.:

```
for (std::string::const_iterator begin(s.begin()), it(begin), end(s.end());
     end != (it = std::find(it, end, '\n'); begin = ++it) {
    std::string line(begin, it);
    // do something with the line
}
```

It may be easier to use the stream functionality with a stream created from you `std::string` as was pointed out.